# Family Sharing working on iOS 8 but not on Yosemite

Tags: itunes, icloud, family-sharing

I have set up a family group and added my husband. From his iPhone running iOS 8 he is able to see and download my purchases, but it is not working from iTunes on Yosemite. There is no trace of my account on his Purchased page.  We've logged him out and in of iTunes, the App Store and even iCloud, and restarted the computer,to no avail. He has only one Apple ID and is logged in under that ID on all devices. All is working in the other direction; I can see his account in my iTunes on Yosemite.  What can we do to fix this, or even troubleshoot it? Nothing is written to the console when I load the Purchased page in iTunes on his computer.

Comment: Try downloading a new freebie app on each machine, that's been known to jog the server's memory

Comment: Glad it helped - done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The severs seem to get stuck sometimes when you set up Family Sharing.

Best way I've found to jog their elbow is just to download any new freebie app.

Comment: Kind of crazy that that is needed, but it seems to have done the trick.

Comment: For sure - server voodoo… works best on alternate Tuesdays, when there's no 'R' in the month… but only if you're facing East ;))